# wp_localize_script not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code in my theme `functions.php` but when I call `console.log(pw_script_vars);` the variable is `undefined`. What did I miss?

```
function mytheme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_scripts');

function pw_load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('pw-script');
    wp_localize_script('pw-script', 'pw_script_vars', array(
            'alert' => __('Hey! You have clicked the button!', 'pippin'),
            'message' => __('You have clicked the other button. Good job!', 'pippin')
        )
    );


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pw_load_scripts');
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You didn't include any javascript file with your `wp_enqueue_script`.

```
function pw_load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('pw-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.js');
     wp_localize_script('pw-script', 'pw_script_vars', array(
            'alert' => __('Hey! You have clicked the button!', 'pippin'),
            'message' => __('You have clicked the other button. Good job!', 'pippin')
        )
    );


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pw_load_scripts');
```

Create an empty file called `test.js` in your theme directory and 
it will work.

If you then look at your source code you'll see:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var pw_script_vars = {"alert":"Hey! You have clicked the button!","message":"You have clicked the other button. Good job!"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

You can then type `pw_script_vars.alert` in your console to get the `"Hey! You have clicked the button!"` message.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my intention was to pass some php arrays in jquery where I can appeal on every page of my template ...

Comment: That's exactly what the code above did. Did you have any issues?

Comment: I got the script from: http://papermashup.com/jquery-iphone-style-ajax-switch/ and I made:  wp_enqueue_script('ajax-switch', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/includes/ajaxswitch/jquery.iphone-switch.js', false, false);
 global $current_user;
 wp_localize_script('ajax-switch', 'ajax_switch', array(
    'post_status' => get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_fbpost_status', true),
    'templateUrl' => get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/ajaxswitch/'
    )
  );

And worken thank you so much, the second thing is that in those php files I need to include the wordpress variables and php library. How?

Comment: The response was `#specify host or domain (needed for wp-includes/ms-settings.php:100)
$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] = 'localhost';

#location of wp-load.php so we have access to database and $wpdb object
$wp_load_loc = "../../../../../wp-load.php";

require_once($wp_load_loc);
`

Answer (score 4):

You could also try to localize jQuery without the need to create additional empty JS files.

```
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'pw_script_vars', array(
        'alert' => __('Hey! You have clicked the button!', 'pippin'),
        'message' => __('You have clicked the other button. Good job!', 'pippin')
    )
);
```

It works like a charm for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Place the code block below the wp_enqueue_script    



     $dir_url = array( 'dir_url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
        wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'adact_img', $dir_url );



Then Add it as a variable on your custom script. Here is called "custom-js"



    var dir_url = adact_img.dir_url;
       $('hello') .owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                loop: true,
                margin: 0,
                dots: false,
                nav: true,
                navText: ["<img src='"+ dir_url +" /assets/images/icons/angle-right.png' />", "<img src='"+ dir_url +" /assets/images/icons/angle-left.png' />"],
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Place the code block below the wp_enqueue_script
```

```
Then Add it as a variable on your custom script. Here is called "custom-js"



    var dir_url = adact_img.dir_url;
       $('hello') .owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                loop: true,
                margin: 0,
                dots: false,
                nav: true,
                navText: ["<img src='"+ dir_url +" /assets/images/icons/angle-right.png' />", "<img src='"+ dir_url +" /assets/images/icons/angle-left.png' />"],
            });
```